# Starting a NServiceBus Endpoint in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azure-functions, azureservicebus

What I would like to do is just what the title says. Start a NServiceBus SendOnly endpoint within an Azure Function. I created a new Azure Functions project and added a new method. Within the method I tried creating an endpoint using the LearningTransport and using the AzureServiceBusTransport but anytime I try to start the endpoint an exception is thrown. I've tried the same code within an Azure Web App project and it worked fine so I'm wondering if there's something unique with Azure Functions.

```
public static void ServiceBus() 
{
    var endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("EndpointName");
    endpointConfig.SendOnly();
    endpointConfig.UsePersistence<LearningPersistence>();
    endpointConfig.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();

    var endpoint = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfig).Result;
}
```

The LearningTransport results in an exception with:

`Couldn't find the solution directory for the learning transport.`

Using the Azure transport with Forwarding Topology results with this exception:

`Can't find any behaviors/connectors for the root context (NServiceBus.Pipeline.ITransportReceiveContext)`

with a stack trace of:

`` at NServiceBus.PipelineModelBuilder.Build()
   at NServiceBus.StepRegistrationsCoordinator.BuildPipelineModelFor[TRootContext]()
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline`1..ctor(IBuilder builder, ReadOnlySettings settings, PipelineModifications pipelineModifications)
   at NServiceBus.StartableEndpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() ``

I've looked everywhere I can think of and haven't found anyone using NServiceBus within an Azure function only the Web Apps. Ideally The function class would have an endpoint it would open in the constructor and then the functions would process webhook information before sending it through the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a proof of concept of integration NServiceBus into Azure Functions now here:

https://github.com/tmasternak/NServiceBus.Functions

Answer (score 0):

Learning transport makes assumptions about file system. Make sure what [you provide](https://docs.particular.net/transports/learning/?#usage-storage-directory) is valid for Functions.

As for using Learning transport - it will be emitting messages on the file system of the random machine you're using. Is that really what you're trying to do or you'd like to use a transport that would send out a message for your other endpoints to process? I'd think something like [Azure Service Bus transport](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/) would be a better option.

Comment: I was just providing additional information. Learning transport isn't what I intend to use within a production environment. I would like to use Azure transport which was the other option I provided that I was having issues with. That was returning an error regarding "ITransportReceiveContext" that I can't find any additional information on how to fix.

Comment: What version of NServiceBus bus are you using it with?

Comment: I've tried 6.4.3 and the latest 7.0.0 beta. I think there's an issue with Azure Functions. You're supposed to be able to chose between Framework and Core when creating an Azure Function project but it always seems to be running with Core. Even with the NSB 7.0.0 beta which is supposed to work with core it still fails to start the endpoint. I can get everything to work with Web Apps just not with Functions.

Comment: The current Azure Service Bus transport will not work on .NET Core. It has to be a Full framework.

Comment: Even the 7.0.0 libraries? Documentation reads that they support core. Alternatively is there a way to use .NET Framework for Azure Functions instead of using Core?

Comment: Could you please point to the documentation that lead you to think so? Current Azure Service Bus transport cannot run on the .NET Core as the client its using was not built to support .NET Standard. Instead, a new transport will be added to support ASB on .NET Core. More details [here](https://particular.net/blog/a-new-azure-service-bus-transport-but-not-just-yet). As for the Functions on .NET Framework, I believe v1 of Functions is on full framework.

Comment: There is now an alpha available of the .net core version of the Azure Service Bus transport for NServiceBus here: https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus-netstandard/

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution on Azure functions version 1 where I tried to put NServiceBus endpoint to use. I also got the same exception: *Can't find any behaviors/connectors for the root context (NServiceBus.Pipeline.ITransportReceiveContext)*.

With Azure functions, NServiceBus does not seem to find the assemblies it needs. Thus the exception. Instructing NServiceBus to scan AppDomain assemblies removed the exception.

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName);
var scanner = endpointConfiguration.AssemblyScanner();
scanner.ScanAppDomainAssemblies = true;
```

According to documentation, AppDomain assembly scanning option should be true by default, but at least in my case I had to set it explicitly.
More info on the topic here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning